# Check if one has already logged into Bloomberg (via API)

Tags: bloomberg

Is there a way to test if current user has been authenticated to BBG? I have my c# program which uses BBG API, and want to check if the user logged in the service **before**, either via API calls or the BBG Terminal. This check can then be used to distinguish whether the user's network is unavailable or simply he hasn't logged in yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to interpret your question, so I'll answer both... (I'm speaking from the perspective of using the Java API, but it should be pretty similar on C#.)

**1. Can I tell whether the user connect to Bloomberg (i.e. are there network issues / are they are logged in)?**

Yes - you can create a new `Session`, try to start it using `.start()`. If it fails or returns false, you cannot connect. If it starts, you can call `.openService("//blp/apiauth")`. Again, if it fails or returns false, you cannot connect.

If you cannot connect, you may or may not be able to determine why you cannot... Nevertheless, I would suggest registering a callback to the BLP API logging framework. In our code, we we-direct these to the logging framework we use throughout our code.

**2. The user has created a `Session` (pre-cursor to a `Service`) - can I tell if the `Session` has been started?**

Unfortunately - no. There is nothing in the API to allow you to determine the state of the `Session`. (I suppose you could try starting it, and if it starts it wasn't started, and if it fails, it was started - but that strikes me as an unhelpful or risk appraoch.)